# How to traverse Taxonomy Tree in Apache Lucene?

Tags: search, lucene, facet, taxonomy

I have a Lucene application that indexes documents and uses facets.

I want to fetch/get all the existing facets in Taxonomy index. How can I traverse the taxonomy tree?